# Macro Parameter in horizontal Mode

Tags: errors

I have read a bunch of pages about "Macro parameters in horizontal mode" but have no idea what it means.

It is preventing me, though from compiling the following. I've read it over and fiddled with it a whole bunch, but it just seems similar to many other files I've made that work just fine.

What's going on?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{int(random(0,10))}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{int(10-\A)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\C}{int(\A+\B)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\D}{int(random(0,9))}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\E}{int(9-\D)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\F}{int(\D+\E)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{int(1,6)}
}

\newcommand{\Variables}
{%
\InitVariables

\A

\B

\C

\D

\E

\F
}

\begin{document}

\Variables

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX predefines `\r`. ***Don't*** use one letter macro names ***unless*** you're sure that they aren't defined. ***Don't*** use a macro name as argument to `\pgfmathsetmacro` unless you know that it is free<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup> If you are using `\pgfmathsetmacro` inside a `\foreach` cycle, then there's little to worry about, as each cycle is performed in a group and values will be restored at the end of the group.</sup>

The error can be reproduced with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{int(1,6)}

\end{document}
```

The same happens whenever the argument to `\pgfmathsetmacro` is an already existing macro defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` (or equivalent method).

Comment: Got it... I didn't know that creating arguments called `\r` was a problem outside of `\foreach` loops. Thanks!